# Running Total-Order By Date in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE [TBL_test] ([ID] int PRIMARY KEY,[RDate] CHAR(10),[Debtor] int,
    [Creditor] int);

    insert into [TBL_test] values(1,'2012/10/11',100,0);
    **insert into [TBL_test] values(2,'2012/11/02',20,0);**
    insert into [TBL_test] values(3,'2012/11/09',0,5);
    **insert into [TBL_test] values(4,'2012/11/02',0,10);**

    select *,(select sum(t2.Debtor - t2.Creditor) from TBL_test t2 where t2.rdate <=
    t1.rdate                
    order by rdate) as RT
    from TBL_test t1
    order by rdate
```

Result

```
ID  RDate       Debtor  Creditor    RT
1   2012/10/11  100     0           100
2   2012/11/02  20      0           110
4   2012/11/02  0       10          110
3   2012/11/09  0       5           105
```

Please advice how can I do to fix the problem on

Comment: What problem needs to be fixed exactly?

Comment: This method makes the calculation wrong.
Record 2 and 3

Comment: The calculation is "right" with the grouping you specify. How do you identify which one of row id 2 or 4 should be "first" in your results?

Comment: Sorry my english is not good
That's my problem too.
Suppose that users will forget their information recorded in the current day and the next day she will do it.
Now we need to calculate the date the records will.

Comment: Farshid, there's no magic. If there is nothing in the data to tell what record is "earlier" than another, there's no way for the database to know. You could probably use the `id` column as a secondary order key to get something stable, but that might not be the "right" result according to how you view it.

Answer (score 0):

not a proof solution, but might work for you, without the need to change datevalues

```
select *,(select sum(t2.Debtor - t2.Creditor) from TBL_test t2 where (t2.rdate < t1.rdate) or (t2.rdate = t1.rdate and t2.ID <= t1.ID) ) as RT
from TBL_test t1
order by rdate,ID
```