# calculated field-running total

Tags: delphi

I'm used to calculate the balance of the calculated field., But when I connect the dbgrid. Calculated by moving the scroll is wrong.
Please get help

```
var
 Form1: TForm1;
 i : Integer;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 i := 0;
 DataSource1.DataSet := ADOTable1;
 DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;
end;

 procedure TForm1.ADOTable1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
  begin
   i := (ADOTable1Debtor.AsInteger - ADOTable1creditor.AsInteger) + i;
   ADOTable1Total.AsInteger := i;
  end;
```

Now run the application and move the scroll in dbgrid column numbers (total) will change.
I'd like to know how to stop the change.

Comment: What is `i`? Where is it initialized? Question is very unclear. Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Initial value in formshow.delphi xe3.When you move the mouse or keyboard dbgrid with the field calculation is wrong.

Comment: Why did you tag delphi-7 and delphi-xe2 then? Please try and be accurate. As for the question, I cannot make any sense of it. I really have no idea what you are doing and what you are asking. Perhaps some more code would help.

Comment: This is not the fault of Delphi.'s Why this is happening in all versions of Delphi.

Comment: Indeed. In that case, you could simply omit the version tags. Which I just did. But we're getting side tracked. You say "Why is this happening?" The question doesn't make it at all clear what is happening. We cannot see enough code. You need to improve the question. If you won't, then I will vote to close it.

Comment: Alright. Then just a sample and I just put the link. Thank

Comment: Please check the link below. Written with Delphi xe3  [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?8vrp2bnpjnsdvf8)

Comment: We need the code visible in the question. Offsite links are no good.

Comment: I tried to make my question clearer. Thank

Answer (score 3):

The calculated fields is designed to **show value calculations at the row level** and is **not designed** to make aggregations (calculations based on a set of rows).

For example, the database layer will fire the `OnCalc` event in no particular order and every time is needed to obtain the value of the field (for display pruposes, for example), since that value is not stored and may (and usually do) depend  on the values of other fields.

In a set of 10 rows, you can get it called for rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and then in 1 again...

You can use it, for example, in a line_total column which is the product of `quantity` and `unit_price`, but you can't use it to show e.g. the `sum(line_total)` of all the lines, as I infer you're trying to do in the shown code.

**How to perform aggregations then?**

You may want to link your DataSet to a ClientDataSet, which have AggregateFields, in which you can perform calculations like `SUM(Quantity * Price)` on the entire row-set or sub-sets based on a Index.

To learn more about AggregateFields read [ClientDataSet Aggregates and GroupState](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29272) by Cary Jensen in EDN.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying can't work, since any scroll will change the result.
Take a AdoDataset instead with following Commandtext

```
select ID, creditor, Debtor,(Select sum (Debtor-Creditor) from Table1 t where t.ID<=Table1.ID) as Total
from Table1 order by ID
```

Comment: Thank you., But the problem with this method again to eat.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439687/running-total-order-by-date-in-sqlite)